# Smooth cut-off function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I am studying the book `Smooth Manifolds and Observables' by Jet Nestruev, and I can't solve part 2 of the following exercise:

**Exercise:** Let $f$ be the function
$
f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl} e^{-\frac{1}{x}} & \textrm{if }x>0,\\
0 & \textrm{if } x\leq 0.
\end{array}\right.
$

Let $c_k=\|f^{(k)}\|_\infty$.

1. Prove that $c_k<\infty$.
2. Investigate the behavior of the sequence $\{c_k\}$ when $k\rightarrow \infty$.

**What I did so far:** I showed that for $x>0$,
$$
f^{(k)}=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}} p_k(x)}{x^{2k}},
$$
where $p_k$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k-1$. This was enough for part 1.

For part 2, more careful estimates seem to be needed. The modulus of the leading coefficient of $p_k$ seems to be $k!$. Perhaps this is useful.

**Motivation for this particular exercise:** This exercise seems to be useful in the proof of Proposition 2.4 on the following page. While the statement of Prop. 2.4 is believable, I am having trouble understanding the rather terse proof there. I suspect there are some typos there. I would be grateful for any help with the above exercise, or in understanding the proof of Prop. 2.4!

The pages on which this appears are pages 14 and 15, and these are available on the google preview of the book
[here](https://books.google.se/books?id=Bz78DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=smooth%20manifolds%20and%20observables&hl=sv&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=smooth%20manifolds%20and%20observables&f=false) .

Comment: Your question is sensible only for people who own the book in question.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I have now added a google preview link of the book, and fortunately it contains the pages of the exercise and also of Prop. 2.4 and its proof. Thanks!

Comment: No, this exercise is not needed at all in the subsequent discussion/proof. Numerical computation suggests that $c_k\to\infty$, but who knows …

Comment: @Ted: Thanks. In the proof of Prop. 24, I think the M_k ought to be the sup over all p. Otherwise I don't see why the series converges unformly (and the series seems to contain an extra f_k which should not be there). If the M_k is the sup over all p, then I don't follow why it is finite (and that us why I thought that maybe it has something to do with this Exercise, since this exercise does seem to provide the asympotics for ||f^{(k)}||_\infty (althogh for a different f obtained after composition with 1-||x||^2).